# SQL SERVER 2016 - Distribution Server compatibility

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

Can you create an SQL SERVER 2016 distributer that merges data between a 2008 R2 server to another 2008 R2 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This is covered in [Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx):

> For all types of replication, the Distributor version must be no
>   earlier than the Publisher version. (Frequently, the Distributor is
>   the same instance as the Publisher.)

Since your Distributor version is a later version than your Publisher version, you are good here.